# string being initialized to 0 for unknown reason

Tags: java, string, initialization

I have a java class called DIE, which has two string fields: location and type. I also have a class called Tag which extends DIE and adds a new int field: level. I have some code that basically says

```
Tag tag = (Tag) (die);
System.out.println(tag);
```

Which prints out -

```
Tag- location: b type: compile_unit level: 0
```

Most of that makes sense, but what I dont understand is why level is being printed out as a zero, or how that value was even evaluated. This is the constructor code for Tag -

```
Tag(String location, String type, String level) {
    super(location, type);
    this.level = Integer.parseInt(level);
}
```

So how does the value 0 appear?

Comment: What `level` value are you passing in to the constructor?

Comment: None... that is the confusing part. Im passing a down casted DIE, which tag extends from. I dont understand how it is deriving a zero value for level.

Comment: What do you mean by "none"? `null`? Or an empty string? Your `die` must have been constructed as `Die die = new Tag(location, type, level)`. If `die` isn't of type `Tag`, you'll get a ClassCastException.

Comment: die isn't of type tag, tag is of type die. It was constructed as Die die = new Die(location, type). Since tag is a die the downcasting works without a classcastexception.

Comment: There's something else wrong here. If you did `Die die = new Die(...); Tag tag = (Tag)die;` then you should have seen a `ClassCastException`: You can't downcast an object to something it's not. You must have called the `Tag` constructor at some point.

Comment: @CameronSkinner is right, that's what I was trying to say. Downcasting shouldn't work here. If it does works, it means that `die` has been constructed as a `Tag`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you aren't passing any `level`, then `String level` would be initialized to `NULL`. Although the [javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String%29) state you should have a `NumberFormatException` if you don't pass a valid number, it is possible that `parseInt` parses your string as `0`.

Even if it didn't though, Java initializes all values to 0 on its own. Make sure you pass a valid level value and try again.

Comment: re `" Java initializes all values to 0 on its own."` --Rather, Java has specific rules about how it initializes the default values for specific types, 0 for int, long, byte, 0.0 for float and double, null for reference variables, false for boolean...

Comment: Thats what I thought would happen, but I was expecting that I would get some sort of null pointer exception or something. Oh well.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels You are correct, 'init all values to 0' is the pedestrian version of your comment